# How to receive notifications about all activities on the repos I have an access to without subscribing to each one manually

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

How to receive notifications about all activities (new repos created, new branched created, new commits, new pull requests, etc) on the repos I have an access to (my own and team-related) without subscribing to each one manually? Is there any built-in way to achieve such behavior or should I create my own application using BitBucket REST API? In the latter case what is the best way to do it? What methods should I look for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a olution for this? I went through the API but didn't find a suitable endpoint, and having to manually go through 20+ repositories is not exactly nice

Comment: @stijn No. I think that you should do it manually via BitBucket API for each of your repositories

Comment: Problem is I didn't even find any method in the API to do it per repository - that would be a start already since looping over them isn't exactly the problem in a script

Comment: @stijn If you're still interested in such solution, I just created a project named bitbucketeye that sends notifications to Slack about any changes in repos available for the specified user on Bitbucket -- https://bitbucket.org/b0r3d0m/bitbucketeye

Comment: interesting. So if I use it, it doesn't require me to go to every single reporistory's Overview page, click the eye icon, set 'watching' on, and manually turn on notifications for commits/PRs etc?

Comment: Ok nevermind, went through the code and noticed it's a 'pull model' (or whatever it is called)

Comment: @stijn Yes, you don't have to set anything in the projects' settings at all. Just launch this script and wait for notifications in the specified Slack's channel